# Postgres Input out of range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to make a SQL statement that finds all the records that are within a certain radius of a given latitude and longitude. When running this query I get an

> input is out of range error

on it. I have two datapoint that are in the table one is the latitude and the other is the longitude both a decimal values.

The query:

```
 $events = Event::whereRaw("acos(sin(latitude * 0.0175) * sin(${lat} * 0.0175)
               + cos(${lat} * 0.0175) * cos(${lat} * 0.0175) *
                 cos((${lng} * 0.0175) - (longitude * 0.0175))
              ) * 3959 <= 35")->paginate(7);


select *
from events
where acos(sin(latitude * 0.0175) * sin(34.1321461 * 0.0175)
  + cos(34.1321461 * 0.0175) * cos(34.1321461 * 0.0175) *
    cos((-90.0594395 * 0.0175) - (longitude * 0.0175))
        ) * 3959 <= 35
```

I had no problem running this on MySQL database that I have also been working on for another project. Not sure what is going on here.

This query should return all the events within a certain radius in this case a 35 mile of the given lat and long.

Comment: If your problem is regarding a specific language and framework other than SQL it's worth mentioning. This doesn't seem like SQL problem. It's more of a ORM-based issue of getting this query to work. Or you could probably obtain the plain SQL being generated and sent to the database itself and share it with us, along with the exact error, sample data, input you are providing and expected result :-).

Comment: its an sql problem I get the same error when I write the sql in my console.

Comment: It would help to show the query you write in the console with the values you are using.

Comment: I attached an example of an SQL statement as you should be able to see the problem is some where in the were clause of the statement

Comment: It seems that your problem is simply reproducible by `select acos(1.1);` query. Something wrong with mathematics.

Comment: For some reason valid lat and longs are returning 1.01

Comment: @JohnDek would be an option to use PostGIS?

Comment: That is something I would have to do some research on since I am using heroic Postgres